# How to approach a static analysis when objects are on differing inclines?

Tags: forces, geometry, statics

I think this sort of problem is known and relatively simple when on a single angle of incline, but I'm trying to understand a problem with two points of contact of a uniform vehicle where each contact point is on a different incline, ie. the front point is in contact with an incline at theta1 and the back respectively at theta2.

I think in a static analysis really the only forces I might need to consider are the reaction forces due to self weight and static friction forces along each respective incline. I know how to approach this problem when it comes to a vehicle on **one** slope but I'm not sure on how to work out the weight distribution when there are **two** slopes involved. I want to use this to see if I can figure out the resulting angle of tilt that the vehicle body is at, maybe "theta3" and to figure out the relative heights between the front and back wheels. Conceptually I think I get that its a force balance and geometry problem but I'm just not quite sure if I'm going about it in the right way.

For simpler discussion we could consider the front and back wheels (centre) are a distance Lf and Lb, and a vertical height of h from the centre of gravity of the vehicle. Any ideas?